# JAX-WS proxy needs

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, proxy

Let we'r writing a web-client for JAX-WS. With `@WebServiceRef` we create proxy, further we creating a specific servlet which sent `http` request `WebService` through proxy. And for what we need in proxy? Why we cant interact with `WebService` directly without proxy? Does proxy hides complexity of interecting with `WebService` Directly? If yes, how it occuring?

Comment: possible duplicate of [proxy object in JAX-WS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266423/proxy-object-in-jax-ws)

Comment: If you want to provide more information, because your question is on hold, then please edit the question (button below the tags) instead of re-posting it.